# Hero section appears on top section of screen even after scrolling down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, styling

I have a hero section and a transparent navbar with a fixed top position. After I scroll down the page, some portion of the hero section still appears at the top of the page.

The white background of the hero section still appears after scrolling down

[image]

Here is the HTML code of the hero section and the navbar (I use Bootstrap)

```css
body {
  background-color: #5c4084 !important;
  padding-top: 75px;
}

.hero-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -75px;
}

.navbar {
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
}

.nav-link {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

#hero-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!--Hero section-->
<section class="hero-section d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div id="hero-container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="text-black">MGMT Methylation Analysis</h1>
        <p class="text-bg-dark lead">
          Analyze MRI scans and predict MGMT Methylation Status
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img src="../static/pexels-cottonbro-studio-5723875.jpg" alt="MRI scans" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--Navbar-->
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light mx-0 fixed-top bg-transparent">
    <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
      <img src="../static/brain.png" alt="MGMT Methylation Analysis" width="60" height="54" style="margin-left: 15px;" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
      <span class="ms-2">MGMT Methylation Analysis</span>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

How can I rectify this?

I have included negative value for `margin-top` as my transparent navbar was not overlapping the hero section.